# ASP Classic regex behaves different than in .Net

Tags: regex, asp-classic, vbscript

I have this regex, that works in .Net - but not in ASP Classic. It also works on [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?30hbf)

It is used to replace spaces with comma, unless the space is inside quotes.

```
dim strSearch
dim strPattern
strPattern = "\s(?=(?:[^\x22]*\x22[^\x22]*\x22)*[^\x22]*\z)" '\x22 = " (dbl quotes)

strSearch = The "quick brown" fox jumps

strSearch = ereg_replace(strSearch, pattern, ",", true)

response.write(strSearch)

'Expect: The,"quick brown",fox,jumps
'Actual: The "quick brown" fox jumps

function ereg_replace(strOriginalString, strPattern, strReplacement, varIgnoreCase)
    dim objRegExp : set objRegExp = new RegExp
    with objRegExp
    .Pattern = strPattern
    .IgnoreCase = varIgnoreCase
    .Global = False
    .Multiline = False
    end with
    ereg_replace = objRegExp.replace(strOriginalString, strReplacement)
    set objRegExp = nothing
end function
```

What do I need to change to adapt the pattern to work in ASP Classic?

Comment: `"\x22"` isn't a space. It is a double quote: `"`. Space is `"\x20"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am pretty sure the reason for this is that `\z` anchors are not supported by ASP regex, try replacing that with `$`:

```
\s(?=(?:[^\x22]*\x22[^\x22]*\x22)*[^\x22]*$)
```

See this page on [VBScript’s Regular Expression Support](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html) for additional information.